# OpenCV - Calculating edge strength of image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

I am new to image processing and I need to calculate the strength of edges present in an image. Assume a situation where you have an image and you add blur effect to that image. The strength of the edges of these two images are different. I need to calculate *that* edge strength for both images separately.

So far I have got the canny edge detection of the image using the code below.

```
  Mat src1;
  src1 = imread("D.PNG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  namedWindow("Original image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("Original image", src1);
  Mat gray, edge, draw;
  cvtColor(src1, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  Canny(gray, edge, 50, 150, 3);
  edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);
  namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("image", draw);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
```

Is there any method to calculate of the strength of this edge image..?

Comment: Please define "strength of this edge image". I don't know if you're looking for a large number of edges, or very sharp edges, or something else.

Comment: from this code you get edge image.i want to calculate the strength of edge. that can be mean value for this edge image. you can use sharp edge or large no of edge to calculate that mean value

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. What were your results?

Comment: unable to find a method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[`mean`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) will give you the mean value of your image. If you're using `Canny` as above you can do:

```
Scalar pixelMean = mean(draw);
```

To get the mean of only the edge pixels, you would use the image as the mask as well:

```
Scalar edgeMean = mean(draw, draw);
```

Unfortunately, since `Canny` sets all edge pixels to `255`, your mean will always be `255`. If this is the measure you're looking for, you'll probably want to use `Sobel` (after Gaussian Blur) and calculate the gradients to get the relative edge strengths.